# Django-allauth: FB connect working with oauth2, but not with js-sdk

Tags: django-allauth

I'm trying to connect to FB using django-allauth. Earlier I went with the oauth method and it was working fine, get all the access tokens. But now, I'm trying to run with js_sdk, but cant figure the problem here.

settings.py:

```
SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS = \
{ 'facebook':
    { 'SCOPE': ['email', 'publish_stream','user_birthday'],
      'AUTH_PARAMS': { 'auth_type': 'reauthenticate' },
      'METHOD': 'js_sdk' ,
      'LOCALE_FUNC': lambda request: 'en_US'}}
```

html:

```
   {% load socialaccount %}  
   {% providers_media_js %}
   <a href ="{% provider_login_url "facebook" method="js_sdk" %}">Facebook connect</a>
```

On clicking the Fb connect link, nothing happens as it tries to make a call to javacript:FB_login(''), which doesn't work.

Any help on this would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Placement is important.  It's recommended to include this right after your < body > tag.

```
{% load socialaccount %}
{% providers_media_js %}
```

To slim down to barebones settings for testing, you could also try this:

```
SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS = {
        'facebook':{
        'SCOPE': ['email', 'publish_stream'],
        'METHOD': 'js_sdk',
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you override the default `allauth` templates? If so, please make sure that you add the following to your login template:

```
{% load socialaccount %}
{% providers_media_js %}
```

In the default templates, this happens here:

https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/27e2a8de0fe3c0c2e65ab8337617eb17a359940c/allauth/templates/account/login.html#L28

The tag adds the required Javascript (if any) for the enabled providers.